# get ITextViewer from IEDitorPart (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse RCP question

I open file with:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editorPart = IDE.openEditor(page, file);
```

I also get document with:

```
IDocument doc = ((ITextEditor)editorPart).getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editorPart.getEditorInput());
```

I need to get to text viewer of that document (for creating LinkedModeUI), is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
IEditorPart editorPart = getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor();
if (editorPart != null) {
    ITextOperationTarget target =
            (ITextOperationTarget)editorPart.getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class);
    if (target instanceof ITextViewer) {
        ITextViewer textViewer = (ITextViewer)target;
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) One document can be opened with more than one editor. You'll have to iterate all editors to look for your file's editors.
2) Viewer is encapsulated in editor. I think the only way is extend editor class to add getter. Or redefine it, if viewer is inaccessible from inheritors.