# Caret position of Eclipse text editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a little plugin to move the caret position of an Eclipse text editor to the other side of a selected block. Problem is that I don't find a nice way to discover whether the selection is left-to-right or right-to-left.

I understand there are these alternatives:

- Use a CarretListener in some way. It seems unnecessary and I don't want to.
- Get hold of the underlaying `StyledText` and compare selection with the caret position. Seems to break abstraction because I have to know how the editor is implemented. Another disadvantage is that you would have to use `widgetOffset2ModelOffset` methods on the text viewer to adjust positions.

Can't I get the caret position from my `ITextEditor` or `ISelectionProvider` or something?

Here is my code:

```java
public class SwapCursorSelectionHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    public Object execute( ExecutionEvent event )
    {
        ITextEditor editor;
        try {
            editor = (ITextEditor) HandlerUtil.getActivePartChecked( event );
        } catch ( ExecutionException exc ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( exc );
        }

        ITextSelection sel = (ITextSelection) editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();

        // How to find out if sel is left-to-right or right-to-left?!

        editor.selectAndReveal( ... );

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Update: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this without using the `StyledText`. I think this is weird and I considers placing a bug report suggesting that selection direction information should be added to `ITextSelection`. Before I do this it would be interesting to get the opinion on people here at SO about this proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get the current cursor position is via `ITextViewer.getTextWidget().getCaretOffset()`. Here's an example that prints various text positions in an implementation of `IContentAssistProcessor` that I was working on:

```java
public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int offset) {
    int widgetCaretOffset = viewer.getTextWidget().getCaretOffset();
    if (viewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension5) {
        ITextViewerExtension5 extension = (ITextViewerExtension5) viewer;
        System.out.println(extension.widgetOffset2ModelOffset(widgetCaretOffset));
    }
    System.out.println(JFaceTextUtil.getOffsetForCursorLocation(viewer));
    System.out.println(offset);
    System.out.println(widgetCaretOffset);
    System.out.println(viewer.getSelectedRange());
}
```

I placed the caret at a random place in a document, then moved the mouse close to the beginning of the first line, then triggered the content assistant with various selections. In my case, the textViewer does not implement ITextViewerExtension5, so only four lines print. The output of the code above is below:

With nothing selected:

```
6
794
794
Point {794, 0}
```

With a left-to-right selection created by shift-right (caret blinking on right side of selection):

```
6
794
799
Point {794, 5}
```

Note that the caret position is 799, which equals 794 + 5.

With a left-to-right selection created by shift-left (caret blinking on left side of selection):

```
6
794
794
Point {794, 5}
```

Note that the caret position equals the selection offset.

Also note, although it's not relevant to this question, that the `offset` parameter in `IContentAssistProcessor. computeCompletionProposals()` is always the offset of the selection, not the caret.

If you have an `ITextEditor` instead of an `ITextViewer`, you can get the `ITextViewer` via the method from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359871/1086034) to this question and from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536114/1086034) to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/923342/1086034):

```java
ITextEditor editor;
ITextOperationTarget target = (ITextOperationTarget) editor.getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class);
if (target instanceof ITextViewer) {
    ITextViewer viewer = (ITextViewer) target;

    int widgetCaretOffset = viewer.getTextWidget().getCaretOffset();
    if (viewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension5) {
        ITextViewerExtension5 extension = (ITextViewerExtension5) viewer;
        System.out.println(extension.widgetOffset2ModelOffset(widgetCaretOffset));
    }
    System.out.println(JFaceTextUtil.getOffsetForCursorLocation(viewer));
    System.out.println(offset);
    System.out.println(widgetCaretOffset);
    System.out.println(viewer.getSelectedRange());
}
```

Comment: `ITextViewer.getTextWidget` is what I also ended up using in my code en the end. Thanks for posting an accurate answer to the question!

Comment: If your code is to work on an arbitrary text editor I think you should also call [`JFaceTextUtil.widgetLine2ModelLine`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/fbe99e2e4da55425ce6b8f66d9277017ccb44735/org.eclipse.jface.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/JFaceTextUtil.java#L217) on the resulting offset from `getTextWidget`. At least if you are using the offset with an `IDocument`.

Comment: @Lii Looks like you're right about `widgtLine2ModelLine()`. Thanks. I'll edit my answer. When I tested this, the document start was always in the visible region. I also didn't check that the offset was exactly right, just that it was consistent and reasonable. I'll double-check that.

Comment: @Lii I found some time to check this. Calling `widgtLine2ModelLine()` is incorrect. `StyledText.getCaretOffset()` returns "the caret position _relative to the start of the text_ \[emphasis added\]" per [its javadoc](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html&anchor=getCaretOffset()). My testing confirmed that I always got the correct result, even if the text was scrolled. This makes sense, considering the item is called caret _offset_, not caret _line_.

Comment: I have not really understood the thing with widget and model lines and offsets. In my comment above I was mistaken about which methods to use, but I think you should use `widgetOffset2ModelOffset`, as they do [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/fbe99e2e4da55425ce6b8f66d9277017ccb44735/org.eclipse.jface.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/JFaceTextUtil.java#L447).

Comment: I think that widget and model lines and offsets often have the same values, but they might be different. For example: 1) When line wrapping is used. 2) If you use an advanced editor, that is optimised for handing large texts by only loading part of the text into the GUI widget.

Comment: Another situation in which I suspect that model and widget offsets would differ is if one enables the Java editor feature *Preferences > Java > Editor > [Only show the selected Java Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962612/eclipse-now-shows-only-a-single-method-in-an-editor-pane-after-clicking-on-the-m)*.

Comment: @Lii I edited the example code to use `ITextViewerExtension5`, but note that I can't test it because my viewer, which is an instance of `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer` from Eclipse Indigo, doesn't implement `ITextViewerExtension5`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This solution turned out to be wrong! Thanks to willkil for pointing it out.**

---

This not very elegant piece of code was the most canonical way to achieve this I could find. It uses `ITextEditor.getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class)` and `JFaceTextUtil`. This implies that it depends on a particular editor implementation, but at least I don't have to touch it myself or mess with the `widget2model` methods.

```java
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) {
    try {
        ITextViewer viewer = (ITextViewer)
            ((ITextEditor) HandlerUtil.getActivePartChecked(event))
                .getAdapter(ITextOperationTarget.class);
        int caretOffset = JFaceTextUtil.getOffsetForCursorLocation(viewer);
    } catch (ExecutionException exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `JFaceTextUtil.getOffsetForCursorLocation()` gives the text offset of the [mouse cursor](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.text/blob/master/org.eclipse.jface.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/JFaceTextUtil.java), not the caret.

Comment: @willkil: Hm, is that so? I'm almost sure that it worked for the keyboard cursor at some point... But I also see that I have removed the usage of this method from my code a long time ago, with the comment `// This returns the wrong offset sometimes. Started with Kepler.` Hm. I'll have to investigate this when I have more time. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I thought it worked at first too, but it turned out I naturally leave the mouse cursor near the selection after clicking on that location in the document.